# How do I pass the values of my checkboxes with PHP to mySQL database?

Tags: php, html, sql

Now the value in my database is just "Array". Because, well it is an array. It can see whether I checked at least one thing, or no things at all. If I don't check any checkboxes it returns nothing, if I check at least one thing it returns "Array".

I haven't worked with PHP before, and we didn't get any classes about this, but after a few days of trying I couldn't figure it out.
[image]

```
<?php

// Show all errors (for educational purposes)
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

// Constanten (connectie-instellingen databank)
define('DB_HOST', '');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', '');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');

// Verbinding maken met de databank
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8mb4', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Verbindingsfout: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? (string)$_POST['name'] : '';
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? (string)$_POST['message'] : '';
$found = isset($_POST['found']) ? (string)$_POST['found'] : '';
$msgName = '';
$msgMessage = '';

// form is sent: perform formchecking!
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {

    $allOk = true;

    // name not empty
    if (trim($name) === '') {
        $msgName = 'Gelieve een naam in te voeren';
        $allOk = false;
    }

    if (trim($message) === '') {
        $msgMessage = 'Gelieve een boodschap in te voeren';
        $allOk = false;
    }

    // end of form check. If $allOk still is true, then the form was sent in correctly
    if ($allOk) {
        // build & execute prepared statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO messages (sender, message, found, added_on) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $stmt->execute(array($name, $message, $found, (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

        // the query succeeded, redirect to this very same page
        if ($db->lastInsertId() !== 0) {
            header('Location: formchecking_thanks.php?name=' . urlencode($name));
            exit();
        } // the query failed
        else {
            echo 'Databankfout.';
            exit;
        }

    }

}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <title>Testform</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@csstools/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/contact.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css-algemeen/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="/" class="logo-nav">Loran</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/About">Over mij</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/Work">Projecten</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-content">
                        <a href="/Work/Project1/">Project 1</a>
                        <a href="/Work/Project2/">Project 2</a>
                        <a href="/Work/Project3/">Project 3</a>
                        <a href="/Work/Project4/">Project 4</a>
                        <a href="/Work/Project5/">Project 5</a>
                        <a href="/Work/Project6">Project 6</a>
                        <a href="/Work/Project7/">Project 7</a>
                        <a href="/Work/Project8/">Project 8</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Contact" class="current">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <main class="container">
        <div class="contactformulier">
            <h1>Contacteer mij</h1>
            <p>Heb je een vraag, of wil je samenwerken? Contacteer mij!</p>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-container">
                    <label for="name">Uw naam</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="input-text"/>
                    <span class="message error"><?php echo $msgName; ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-container">
                    <label for="message">Uw bericht</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
                    <span class="message error"><?php echo $msgMessage; ?></span>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-container">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Hoe heeft u mij gevonden?</legend>
                        <div class="fieldset-form">
                            <label for="vrienden">Vrienden</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="found[]" id="vrienden" value="vrienden">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fieldset-form">
                            <label for="socials">Sociale media</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="found[]" id="socials" value="social">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fieldset-form">
                            <label for="google">Google</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="found[]" id="google" value="google">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fieldset-form">
                            <label for="andere">Andere</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="found[]" id="andere" value="andere">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Verstuur"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
    
    <footer>
        <p>Footer &copy; 2021 Loran Maes - <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/loran-maes-524a05160/" target="blank">LinkedIn</a> - <a
                href="https://www.instagram.com/loran_maes/" target="blank">Instagram</a>  - copyright - Dendermondesteenweg 809 9070 Destelbergen</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `found` is supposed to contain a comma-delimited list of the checkbox values, use `implode()` to create that from the array.

```
$found = isset($_POST['found']) ? implode(',', $_POST['found']) : '';
```

However, this is generally poor design. See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: I'll try that, if it works it works. I'm still in my first few months of HTML and I'll get more classes with PHP soon, but this has to work for now, thanks though!
*edit* This works, amazing thank you!!